# how is view controller connected with App Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I was trying to understand the flow of this app: https://github.com/JoelMarcey/iOS-2048

but I am not sure how this app works (absolute beginner)

So we have main.m which happens to be a starting point of the app?
https://github.com/JoelMarcey/iOS-2048/blob/master/NumberTileGame/NumberTileGame/main.m

main.m imports AppDelegate.h

https://github.com/JoelMarcey/iOS-2048/blob/master/NumberTileGame/NumberTileGame/F3HAppDelegate.h

AppDelegate.m does not import ViewController? So how does this App show initial screen and screen thereafter?

Shouldn't there be some code in AppDelegate.m? Can someone please explain me the code?

Also, how do I see Main_iPhone.storyboard in my project and not in repo online?

[image]

Comment: Hint: Info.plist

Answer (score 1):

> AppDelegate.m does not import ViewController? So how does this App show initial screen and screen thereafter?

This is a storyboard-based app. The Info.plist specifies the storyboard to use, and that storyboard specifies the initial scene, which is basically a graph of objects including a view controller and its view hierarchy.

If you open the storyboard file, you'll see an arrow pointing to the first scene, which will likely have an instance of `F3HViewController`. I haven't actually downloaded the project, but that class seems like the obvious candidate since it only has a `-playGameButtonTapped` action that presumably is connected to a "Play" button. That action then instantiates and presents the next view controller, `F3HNumberTileGameViewController`, and gameplay begins.

> Shouldn't there be some code in AppDelegate.m? Can someone please explain me the code?

Only if you want to customize what the application does. In this case the developer doesn't seem to want that.

> Also, how do I see Main_iPhone.storyboard in my project and not in repo online?

It's in the `Base.lproj` [subdirectory](https://github.com/JoelMarcey/iOS-2048/tree/master/NumberTileGame/NumberTileGame/Base.lproj).

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the `NumberTileGame-Info.plist` file, you'll see that there's a reference to a Storyboard. A storyboard is a file that the system uses to load UI elements such as view controllers, including (sometimes) the connections between the controllers.

In this app's case, the storyboard loads `F3HViewController` as the initial view controller. That's why you don't see a reference to the controller in the app delegate. Regarding your question of code in the app delegate, it's not *necessary* to have a bunch of code in the app delegate -- it's an architecture decision that determines what code goes in view controllers, the app delegate, etc.

Regarding your comment about the storyboard, the storyboard *is* in the repo -- it's in `Base.lproj`.

Comment: i never used custom app delegate so please can you explain me why it's used?

Comment: What do you mean by “custom”?

Comment: new app delegate creation except project in built app delegate. like project have 2 app delegate. mate now you got it?

Comment: You can’t have two app delegates.

Comment: if i used custom framework as cordova it have personal one my app has also appdelegate. and i show some project they just change app delegate name as well as them project.

Comment: so how can they target there app delegate now my question is clear?

Comment: No, it’s not clear to me at all. It might be helpful to start a new question rather than trying to express a separate question in the comments of an unrelated question.